# How to configure grouped layers in the LayerList widget with feature layers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, table-of-contents, group-layer

This applies to the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API v4.x.

This [LayerList widget example code](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=widgets-layerlist) contains grouped layers, whereby the San Francisco parent checkbox also controls its child layers:

[image]

The example code uses [a WebScene document](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webscene/viewer.html?webscene=adfad6ee6c6043238ea64e121bb6429a) as the source for the layers, but in my case I'm manually creating the layers as FeatureLayer objects, and adding them to a Map object, using the pattern:

```
const myMap = new Map({basemap: "streets-vector"});
const layer1 = new FeatureLayer({url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/0"});
const layer2 = new FeatureLayer({url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/1"});
myMap.addMany([layer1,layer2]);
```

Using this pattern, is it possible to create layer groups/hierarchies, ie create a parent checkbox for layer1 and layer2?